# Just installed Ubuntu and can't connect to wifi

Tags: wireless

I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux and I just downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.4 but I can't connect to wifi. When I click on wifi in settings, it says that the wifi adapter can't be found. I've tried watching videos addressing this issue and connecting to ethernet but none of the solutions work. I have a thinkpad x1 carbon if that helps.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0030]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please also ass output of `dmesg | grep iwl; uname -a`.